# iOS in-app purchase and iAds

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, iad

I'm trying to test the in-app purchase feature of my iOS app, and I cannot get it to work properly.

The in-app purchase removes all advertisements from the app.

When I run to test in Xcode, the ads show just fine. When I test it on my device, I see no ads and get this in the log:

```
BACKGROUND SAVING (ROOT) ***> on *** MAIN THREAD ***
2014-04-19 11:08:11.828 BalanceApp[227:60b] Feature: Remove Ads, Cost: 1.990000, ID:     com.balanceapp.net.removeads
2014-04-19 11:08:13.579 BalanceApp[227:60b] NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore error: com.balanceapp.net has no valid com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier entitlement
```

The test ads did work the very first time, but then I tested the in-app purchase feature and now I can't view the ads anymore.

I've restored my iOS device and logged in with another account and it still won't work.

I've published my app to the app store and it has been approved. When I go to the iAds section, I see no impressions, no requests, no fill rate — nothing. Although, it does say in iTunes Connect that my Ad status is "Live."

I've had friends download the app and I can't see ads show up on their devices, either.

My app was only published yesterday. Could it take a while for it to show up? How can I at least get the "The iAd network is working on this device" when testing it in Xcode? It does work fine in the simulator, just not on a real device.

Comment: How are you storing that a purchase has been completed? I would review the [In-App Purchase Programing Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction.html) and also the [iAd Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/iAd_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Comment: @jryankennedy, it does take a couple of days for the ads to show up.  My latest app was approved yesterday and still no ads.  Wait a couple of days, I have heard it taking up to three days to figure out what ads they will send to your app.  Keep us posted though.

Comment: @Douglas I did some research and it seems as if that is the case. From what I've ready from various sources online (including Apple's own developer forums) it takes a few days before ads show. I will keep everyone posted about this situation. Hopefully by Monday or Tuesday the ads will be live.